# Is using CreateDocumentQuery with predicate SQL Injection safe when using Cosmos DB?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-cosmosdb, sql-injection

I am using Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core version 2.1.1 library in .NET application to query data from Cosmos DB.

Below is a code that I am using to query the data from Cosmos DB:

```
var query = predicate == null 
    ? docClient.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(CollectionUri, new FeedOptions {..... }).AsDocumentQuery()
    : docClient.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(CollectionUri, new FeedOptions { .....}).Where(predicate).AsDocumentQuery();
```

From the above code my question is, using predicate in query will be SQL injection safe?

Comment: please give an example of what your `predicate` can look like

Comment: predicate will be like x=>x.id=="123" @silent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will indeed be safe.

The SDK is using an internal LINQ to CosmosDB SQL converter which will just convert the LINQ to a query which is a single string. The SDK will use internal classes like `SqlSelectClause`, `SqlWhereClause` etc to contract a safe final result.

You can also see the exact query that your LINQ creates by using `query.ToString()`.

Comment: When I did query.ToString() I got string something like below   ---- {"query":"SELECT VALUE root FROM root WHERE ((root[\"type_name\"] = \"TestEntity\") AND (UPPER(root[\" \"]) = \"SomeValue\")) "}

Comment: And When I tried the same query using SqlQuerySpec class I got ---- 

{"query":"SELECT * FROM TestEntity b WHERE (b.TestId = @id)","parameters":[{"TestId":"@id","value":"SomeValue"}]} . here the query was written by me as string and after viewing using query.tostring() I got above string.

Comment: are both equivalent? @Nick

Comment: @PradeepGaba As you can see those are 2 fundamentally different queries. They are querying for different stuff. In terms of SQL injection they are both equally safe.

Answer (score 0):

It depends:
If you are writing your own SQL Command, you are not safe.
Building your queries using lambda expressions is SQL injection proof.

Having a query like this 
`var id = "5 AND (UPPER(root[\" \"]) = \"SomeValue\")";
query.Where(x => x.Id == id).AsDocumentQuery()` would generate the following query:

```
SELECT VALUE root FROM root WHERE ((root[\"id\"] = \"5\" AND (UPPER(root[\\" \\"]) = \\"SomeValue\\"))
```

It won't evaluate.